# Firebase cloud messaging Отсутсвует сертификат APNS

Tags: ios, firebase, push-уведомления, ionic2

Добрый день, я пытаюсь подключить к приложению push уведомления и наткнулся на такую проблему как сертификат APNS. Я сделал все как указано во всевозможных мануалах, экспортировал и private key и certificate, подключал, естественно все это в консоли firebase однако при попытке отослать тестовое сообщение я натыкаюсь на одну и туже проблему:"Отсутствует сертификат APNS. Загрузите его в настройках."
Может кто с этим сталкивался и может подсказать что я делаю и делаю-ли не так?

Comment: Ваше приложение опубликовано в Аппсторе?